# Make a transparent 3D sphere with objects inside

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, 3d, transparency, perspective

I want to build a 3d sphere as a container which has a blurred transparent surface and wrapped some objects inside. (Objects are placed on the half floor).

I've created something similar, in 2D to clarify the issue:

[image]

(It's been made by the lens flare filter)

So I think the best way to make something 3D like this is **3D menu > New mesh from layer > Mesh preset > Sphere** and then apply the proper material to it. But how could I put some objects in it? What's the best way to show the horizontal cross inside the sphere which would act as its interior floor?

I'm still not sure whether 2D graphic would work or not, and if not, Does photoshop suite this particular issue or a 3D special app like C4D is needed. But Photoshop would be my preferred choice.
**It'll be used in a printed catalog. And All we'd see is The Sphere from front view.**

Thanks

Comment: To get a better answer for a question like this, especially the part about whether 2D or 3D would work please update (edit) your question to state the intended use of the sphere.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure got your scope, What update exactly?

Comment: You asked if a "2D graphic would work or not." But we don't know what this is for? Is it being dropped into a powerpoint presentation to illustrate something? Are you designing a bowling ball? Will it go into a 3D pinball game? Will it even be animated? Etc....

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, It'll be used in a printed catalog. And All we'd see is The Sphere from front view. I added it to the question's description.